# Copy range between sheets, searching for the date in Col-E of OriginalSheet and inserting it between date range of Column A

Tags: excel, date, insert, range, vba

I'm a bit of a Newbie but hopefully you'll be able to help me impress my new boss ;).

My work has a program which outputs a bunch of data into a spreadsheet (can't change this, I only get the info at this point), and from that spreadsheet I've been told to manually copy-paste the range (section one is A8 to H8, section two is A9 to H9, so on), into another spreadsheet based on date (same workbook), inserting a new row to paste.

Workbook is called "Invoices".

Spreadsheet 1 -Original- columns are as follows: Blank, Blank, Blank, Reference, DATE, Memo, Agent, Paid.

Spreadsheet 2 -Transfer-, (sorted by date): Mon Date, Sun Date, Amount Due, Reference, DATE, Memo, Agent, Paid.

So currently I manually:
1. Check the date on the Original page (column E)
2. Go to the Transfer page
3. Look for the date range in which it falls (column A), dates start at A20 if that helps.
4. Insert a new row in that date range
5. Go back to the original page
6. Cut the range A-H
7. Paste it into the newly created row of sheet 2 in cells A-H
8. Recolour the new E cell to be blue.

As you can see, Columns D-H on both pages are the same. If we're able to copy the value of E into A (dates), that'd be amazing but I can live without it.

I have been trying to make a macro to do this, but I just can't get it to work. In a nutshell I want it to look up the date at Original Row E, look it up in Transfer Row A, insert a row BELOW (dates get later as you go down) and then paste that A:H range.

If anyone could help me out I'd greatly appreciate it, and if they can tell me how to loop the macro so it does Row8 (where the data first appears, then goes back and does Row 9, I'd be over the moon. And if it's at all possible, I need it to get the tab name (the sheet name) from cell Z1 on the original page, which I've set up to output automatically. And it must be a macro, not a VBA.

Thanks so much!

Here is my recorded method, as suggested:

```
Sub Macro3()

     'In the sheet I need to TRANSFER to <- This part is fine
        Sheets("Transfer").Select

     'Manually pick random row <- this needs to be done automatically based on comparing value of "Original" E to "Transfer" A.
         Rows("28:28").Select
         Selection.Insert Shift:=xlUp, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

     ' Need to delete otherwise the pre-existing formulas wont flow <- Fine
          Selection.ClearContents

     ' Back to Original sheet <- Fine
           Sheets("Original").Select

     ' Select range I need to transfer <- Fine
              Range("A8:H8").Select
              Selection.Copy

      'Back to TRANSFER sheet <- Fine
              Sheets("Transfer").Select

      'Select the A column of the row I created above. <- Need automated to find the empty row
                Range("A28").Select

       'Paste just the values. <- Find
               Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

And then I would need it to loop back and do the same thing to row 9 and onward, until it reaches the end of the list (which varies in length - might be 5, might be 100.

Here is what happens with the macro, YowE3K (have blacked out private info)

[The "Original" and "Transfer sheets". Transfer is empty and Original has the data I want to copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sp6KP.png)

[What DID happen after running the macro and what I WANTED to happen. The cells all inserted themselves in a block, instead of each row inserting itself into a new row between the appropriate date ranges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NOAf.png)

And the following is something a co-worker uses to pull info from "Water Invoice" (which would be my original), into "Trust". His only has to do one value in a set cell though, mine has to do one then loop back and do the next row.

```
 Sub WaterInvoice3ToTrust()
 Dim water As Workbook
     Set water = Workbooks("Water Invoice.xlsm")
     'Original File
 Dim trust As Workbook
     Set trust = Workbooks("Trust.xlsm")
     'Transfer File
 Dim transfer As String
 Dim found As Range
 Dim search As Date
 Dim Discovered As Integer
 Dim onefrom As String

     On Error Resume Next

 ' Open Transfer file if not open already
     If Err <> 0 Then
         On Error GoTo 0
         Workbooks.Open ("RETRACTED FOR PRIVACY")
     End If

 Discovered = 0

 'Original File
  Workbooks("Water Invoice").Worksheets("00 Template").Activate
 transfer = water.Sheets("00 Template").Range("Z1")  '<--Z1 is the same as my Z1, shows the tab name
 search = water.Sheets("00 Template").Range("AB8")  ' <--This is his date, would be my E8

 'Where to search
 While Discovered = 0
    Set found = trust.Sheets(transfer).Range("A:A").Find(DateValue(search), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not found Is Nothing Then
             Discovered = 1
        End If
            search = search - 1
         Wend


 'What to put in each cell <- I can edit this part myself, no worries
     trust.Sheets(transfer).Rows(found.Row).EntireRow.Insert
    trust.Sheets(transfer).Cells(found.Row - 1, "A") = water.Sheets("00 Template").Range("AB8")
     trust.Sheets(transfer).Cells(found.Row - 1, "B") = "-"
     trust.Sheets(transfer).Cells(found.Row - 1, "C") = water.Sheets("00 Template").Range("Z6")
     trust.Sheets(transfer).Cells(found.Row - 1, "D") = water.Sheets("00 Template").Range("AB8")
     trust.Sheets(transfer).Cells(found.Row - 1, "E") = "Water Usage"
     trust.Sheets(transfer).Cells(found.Row - 1, "F") = "RETRACTED"
     trust.Sheets(transfer).Cells(found.Row - 1, "G") = "$0.00"

'Cell formatting
  'No idea what this does, assume formatting?
        onefrom = "G" & found.Row - 2
            trust.Activate
                trust.Sheets(sheeet).Activate
                    trust.Sheets(sheeet).Range(onefrom).Select
                        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Selection.Resize(3, 1), Type:=xlFillDefault

        'No idea what this does, assume formatting?
        onefrom = "M" & found.Row - 2
            trust.Activate
                trust.Sheets(sheeet).Activate
                    trust.Sheets(sheeet).Range(onefrom).Select
                        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Selection.Resize(3, 1), Type:=xlFillDefault

        'No idea what this does, assume formatting?            
        onefrom = "N" & found.Row - 2
            trust.Activate
                trust.Sheets(sheeet).Activate
                    trust.Sheets(sheeet).Range(onefrom).Select
                        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Selection.Resize(3, 1), Type:=xlFillDefault

        'This seems to make his E cell blue
        onefrom = "E" & found.Row - 1
            trust.Sheets(sheeet).Range(onefrom).Select
                With Selection.Interior
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .Color = 15773696
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                End With

 'Go Back to Original workbook
 water.Activate

 ' Message Boxes <- I can edit this myself
     On Error Resume Next
         If Err Then
             MsgBox "Water was NOT entered into Trust.", vbExclamation
                 Else
                     MsgBox "Water was entered into Trust.", vbInformation
         End If
         On Error GoTo 0

 End Sub
```

Comment: Paste what you have written so far into the question.  Then narrow your question down to show which bit you are **currently** stuck on (not your entire task if you are stuck on "how do I get the date from the Original page").

Comment: Thanks YowE3K I have done as you asked.

Comment: I just noticed a statement in your question that I didn't notice this morning. (Hey - it was about 2am - I wasn't paying much attention!)  You say "And it must be a macro, not a VBA".  Usually people call VBA code a "macro" - what do you see as the difference between the two?  (You pasted VBA code into the question, so I'm very confused.)

Comment: My apologies, I was under the impression a VBA was automatic (for example I have a "VBA" set up to alphabetize all my tabs without my needing to trigger it, and a macro had to be run manually. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

All macros are basicly pieces of code written in VBA.

I'd suggest you try out the macro recording feature. Just record the main idea, select X range then copy it to an other sheet.

Once you done that, you can tweak the code to fit your needs.

Comment: Hi, thanks I did try recording one - but I have no idea how to automate the "looking up dates and inserting row based on cell value of E" thing. If it was just copy-paste into a fixed cell on a certain page, I could do that no problem. But it's the date search that has me stuck. And making it go row by row individually searching, because what might be row 8-9-10 on the Original page might end up being 17-25-34 on the Transfer once you put in the dates right.